Timber/Twig Component include with associated PHP
I have a footer section where I need to include a list of custom post types on some of my templates.
I was planning to do something like this:
{% if display_featured_issues %}
  {% include "partials/blocks/featured-issues.twig" %}
{% endif %}

And some templates set the flag to true.
However, how can I make sure the required featured-issues.php file executes when this template part is included? I need to pull the latest featured issues from the Database. I don't want to do that globally, only when this template part is included.

You can add a custom function to the twig instance which you can call in the included template

I'm on V1 of Timber, I should add...

Documentation for v1 can be found here

Thank you. I can create a custom function but it seems very cumbersome, I am surprised there is not a more straightforward way to connect a template part with a PHP file to get the data

How is this not straightforward?
